# ASP.net Core Web API - correct swagger annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, openapi

I am writing a Web API and have defined a controller with various GET, POST methods etc.  I am using Swagger Open API for my documentation and want to understand the correct way to annotate.  Here's an example of a controller method I have:

```cs
/// <summary>Download a file based on its Id.</summary>
/// <param name="id">Identity of file to download.</param>
/// <returns><see cref="MyFile" /> file content found.</returns>
[HttpGet("download/{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[SwaggerResponse(200, "Myfile content", typeof(MyFile))]
[SwaggerResponse(404, "Could not find file", typeof(MyFile))]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadAsync(int id)
{
    const string mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    var myFile = await _dbContext.MyFiles.FindAsync(id);

    // If we cannot find the mapping, return 404.
    if (myFile.IsNullOrDefault())
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // Download using file stream.
    var downloadStream = await _blobStorage.DownloadBlob(myFile.FileLocation);
    return new FileStreamResult(downloadStream, mimeType) { FileDownloadName = myFile.FileName };
}
```

As you can see, I'm using both ProducesResponseType and SwaggerResponse to describe the download method. I'm a bit confused as to the correct attribute to use - swagger response or produces response type?  Should I use both?  Why would I favor one over the other?

Thanks for any pointers in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using both `ProducesResponseType` and `SwaggerResponse` is not necessary.
It also depends on your action declaration, for example your action returs `Task<IActionResult>`.

Knowing only that (without any additional attributes) a return type from that action might be anything.

So by adding: `[SwaggerResponse(200, "Myfile content", typeof(MyFile))]` attribute to that method, the type `MyFile` is known to be returned from that action and can be documented.

On the other hand you wouldn't need that attribute if you specified that in return type as follows:

```
[HttpGet("download/{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyFile>> DownloadAsync(int id)
```

I got rid of 2 `SwaggerResponse` attributes and the documented return type of this action will still be the same.

I would say the less annotation the better, but of course it depends on your needs ;p

Answer (score 3):

In my case I am already using "SwaggerOperation" annotation to add summary and description to the actions (and highly recommend that), that is why I went on using SwaggerResponse instead of ProducesResponseType anyway. At the end it really should not matter, you can see from source code that SwaggerResponseAttribute is derived from ProducesResponseTypeAttribute:

[image]